# How to detect adjacent entries in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

"Write a method in Java that returns true if there are k adjacent occurrences of a symbol in the same row, column, or diagonal of a checkered board (two-dimensional array), where k is the number of symbols inline desired."

How can I do this? I have a rough idea of how to check rows and columns (very rough; no code, just thoughts) but I'm at a loss for checking the diagonal.

Edit: one other situation I'm thinking about: how can I check arbitrary positions? Right now, I'm only considering occurrences starting at (0,0), but what if there's a string of 3 from, say, (2,3) to (2,6)? How could I keep track of multiple occurrences?

EDIT: Detecting the left diagonal (rough code for a question I posted in the comments below):

```
LeftDiagonal(x, symbol) {
    noOfOccurence = 0;

    for (currentX = (size - 1); currentX >= x; currentX--) {
        if (board[currentX][currentX] == symbol) {
            noOfOccurence++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return (noOfOccurence >= k);
}
```

Comment: `twoDimArray[0][0]` is next to `twoDimArray[0][1]` and `twoDimArray[1][0]` and `twoDimArray[1][1]`. Anything else you need? By the way, there's a pattern right there: `twoDimArray[x][y]`, `twoDimArray[x][y+1]`, `twoDimArray[x+1][y]`, `twoDimArray[x+1][y+1]`.

Comment: A diagonal is merely (x+1, y+1) for any position tuple (x, y).  If you're having any pain on a specific problem, feel encouraged to edit your question addressing such - depending on the nature of the problem, providing code as necessary.

Comment: You should write the code for checking rows first. Get it working. Then move on to columns. Once you get both of those working, diagonals should be fairly obvious.

Comment: I doubt if even your right diagonal code is correct.  You are just moving on x-axis.  In order to check diagonal, you should have something like `x++` and `y++` for right diagonal and `x--` and `y++` for left diagonal.  Honestly I really doubt if you really understand my logic in the answer?.... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest (though not the most efficient as it may backtrack) solution that comes to mind is to write a recursive function, like the following psuedocode

```
 FindAdjacent(x, y)
       if (matrix[x-1][y-1] == matrix[x][y])
            return 1 + FindAdjacent(x-1,y-1);
       .. Repeat for all 7 other adjacent locations (-1, +0) (+0, -1) (+1, -1) (-1, +1) (+1, +1) (+1, 0) (0, +1)
       else return 1;
```

This routine would, given a coordinate x,y, return the of symbols around it in a 'blob'.  
**Note:** This also means grouping of symbols such as 3 in a row, with 1 next to it in a column below.

If you were to call this once for every location in the matrix and see if the returned value once all recursive levels return is `>= k`, that might solve your problem.  Remember to do bounds checking so you do not check matrix[-1][-1] or anything.

Comment: In fact I thought OP is asking for n-occurrence on same row, OR same column, OR diagonally.  your way is to find n-connected cells, connected means two cells are adjacent (and adjacent diagonally).  So I am not sure what you suggested is right.  The biggest problem of your method is, if cell A and B are adjacent, the suggested way is run non-stop coz FindAdjacent(A) will find B, and it will in turns call FindAjacent(B) and will find A, then in turns call FindAdjacent(A)....

Answer (score 0):

You're going to be running a lot of nested loops i would imagine. Don't forget all the diagonals.

```
array[1][1] is just below array[0][1] above array[2][1] to the left of array[1][2] to the right of array[1][0] and diagonal to four different points:

diagonal up and to the left is array[0][0]
diagonal up and to the right is array[0][2]
down and to the left is array [2][0]
down and to the right is array[2][2]

[0][0] | [0][1] | [0][2]
[1][0] | [1][1] | [1][2]
[2][0] | [2][1] | [2][2]
```

I think the array[x][y] is misleading if you graph a lot. array[row][column] is better.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't trust your "Thought". Write the real code out to make sure you can make the row and column checking works.

The idea should be straight-forward:

Loop through the checker board.  Assume the top-left is [0,0], then go right ([0,1], [0,2]...) until you hit the right boundary.  Then go to next line.  Finish until you hit the bottom right box.

For each box, check if there is k occurrence 1. to the right, 2. downward, 3. diagonally to left-down and 4. diagonally to right-down.

If any of the 4 happens, then return true, if not, move to next cell.

As example, here is some sample psuedocode:

Iterate through the board:

```
ROWS=8;
COLS=8;
char[ROWS][COLS] board;
k = 3; // occurrence

for (x = 0 to COLS-1) {
  for (y = 0 to ROWS-1) {
    checkRightward(x, y, k);
    // checkDownward(...)
  }
}
```

a sample checkRightward:

```
checkRightward(x,y,k) {
  char symbol = board[y][x];
  noOfOccurence = 0;
  for (currentX = x; currentX  < COLS ; ++currentX) {
    if (board[y][currentX] == symbol) {
      noOfOccurence++;
    } else {
      break; // jump out from the loop
    }
  }

  return (noOfOccurence >= k);
}
```

Shouldn't be hard for you to translate the idea to Java, and to add the other missing checking.

---

Edit: as the author seems don't really understand what I am talking about... so I make a little visual presentation on the idea:

assume a 8 x 8 board, it something like this:

```
           X
     0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  0
  1
  2
  3        * ---->
Y 4      / | \
  5   |/_  |  _\|
  6        V     
  7
```

In the above diagram, the [x,y] coordinate of the current cell (the position with star * ) is [3,3].  What you have to do is to check

1) rightward:
that means check if [3,3], [4,3], [5,3].... is of the same symbol

2) downward:
that means check if [3,3], [3,4], [3,5].... is of the same symbol

3) right-diagonal: 
that means check if [3,3], [4,4], [5,5].... is of the same symbol

4) left-diagonal: 
that means check if [3,3], [2,4], [1,5].... is of the same symbol

you start your checking from the [0,0] cell, and then [1,0], [2,0]... then [0,1],[1,1][2,1]... until you found a cell with successful of anyone of the 4 checkings, or when you hit the last cell ([7,7]).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I managed to implement this algorithm just fine, and it works great. However, I am having a bit of trouble with checking the left diagonal. Right diagonal works fine, but for some reason, the same isn't true for left diagonal. I have posted my left diagonal code in my question, so if you could give any advice on how I did that, I would appreciate it very much. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<row;i++)
For(j=0;j<column;j++){
current = Arr[row][col];
For(count=0;count<k;count++)
{
If(current==arr[row][col+count])
Flagcol=true
Else
Flagcol=false
}
For(count=0;count<k;count++)
{
If(current==arr[row+count][col])
Flagrow=true
else
Flagrow=false
}
For(count=0;count<k;count++)
{
If(current==arr[row+count][col+count])
Flagdiagnoltrue
Else 
Flagdiagnol=false
}
}
}
```

a very rough draft to give idea.. And remember one thing you will need to check if row+count/col+count should not exceed row/count..else outofbondsexception..:-D